# String replacement within FOR /F into batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

There are a handful of questions on SO that look similar, but I cannot figure out some behaviour and I am looking for help.

Below is a snippet from a batch file I am trying to write which will load in a set of directories and potentially replace letter substitutions with an expanded path, e.g. the properties file might look like:

```dos
location1=C:\Test
location2=[m]\Test
```

Where `location1` points to `C:\Test` and `location2` points to `C:\Program Files(x86)\MODULE\Test`, because `[m]` is a shorthand to `C:\Program Files(x86)\MODULE`.

The batch script, to this point, is simply trying to read in the list of file paths and expand/replace the [m].

```dos
SET build.dir=%~dp0%

SET progfiles=%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%
IF "%progfiles%"=="" SET progfiles=%ProgramFiles%

SET local.properties=%build.dir%local.properties

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%i IN (%local.properties%) DO (

   SET local.dir=%%j
   SET local.dir=!local.dir:[m]=%progfiles%\MODULE!

echo !local.dir!
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Running this kicks out an error:

> \MODULE was unexpected at this time.

If I replace the FOR with the following instead:

```dos
set test="[m]\Proj\Dir"
set test=!test:[m]=%progfiles%\MODULE!
echo %test%
```

I get the desired `C:\Program Files(x86)\MODULE\Proj\Dir` printed out...so I'm confused why it works fine outside of the `FOR` loop.

My understanding about delayed expansion is that it 'expands' at runtime...which you get to happen using `!!` instead of `%%` wrapped around the variable. Furthermore, as I'm creating the `local.dir` variable inside the `FOR` loop scope, I must use delayed expansion in order to access it with the updated value for the iteration.

I feel like the problem is using `%progfiles%`, like there's some special syntax I need to use in order to make it work but nothing is adding up for me. When I `echo %progfiles%`, it prints out as `C:\Program Files(x86` -- note the missing trailing ).

Any ideas? Thanks

---

Tested suggestion:

```dos
D:\Projects\Test\Build>test
*** "D:\Projects\Test\Build\local.properties"
*** "","C:\Program Files (x86)"
[m]=C:\Program Files (x86)\MODULE
```

---

Adding quotes around the whole expression makes it work -- can't use other characters for some reason (like []) -- and since I want to append to the path later, we can safely remove the quotes afterwards:

```dos
SET local.dir="!local.dir:[m]=%progfiles%\MODULE!"
SET local.dir=!local.dir:"=!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this to see if you can nut out the issue:

The double quotes are to provide robust handling in a system with long file/path names.

The `()` are unquoted which are a problem in a batch script, when inside a loop.

```
@echo off
SET "build.dir=%~dp0%"

SET "progfiles=%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%"
IF "%progfiles%"=="" "SET progfiles=%ProgramFiles%"

SET "local.properties=%build.dir%local.properties"
echo *** "%local.properties%"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%i IN ("%local.properties%") DO (

   SET "local.dir=%%j"
echo *** "!local.dir!","%progfiles%"
   SET "local.dir=!local.dir:[m]=%progfiles%\MODULE!"

echo !local.dir!
)
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Comment: can you please update your answer to put the quotes as such: "!local.dir:[m]=%progfiles%\MODULE!" (and remove the others you had added) so I can accept your answer? I think some of the extra quotes (e.g. those around %local.properties%) cause other issues...

Comment: @rguilbault  If you can explain what issues they cause then I can investigate it.  However I am very sure that they cause no issues when used correctly in other parts of your script.  `set "a=123"` `set "b=456"` is then appended like this `set "c=%a%\%b%"` and `echo %c%` has no quotes but `echo "%c%"` does have quotes.

Comment: as written, when I run your script I get the output I edited the OP with the results (under Tested suggestion). the loop only causes 1 set of output for the file list. turns out that simply removing the quotes from %local.properties% from the FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%i IN (%local.properties%) DO (
line was enough to make your solution work -- so my bad for asking you to remove all the quotes. I'm going to accept the answer now, since it's a minor thing and there's enough explanation. thanks!

Comment: @rguilbault  I didn't read the question properly and had mistaken local.properties for a text string and not a file, sorry.  Your solution is fine when the `%local.properties%` contains no spaces or & or some other characters.  Adding `usebackq` as shown and leaving the double quotes in  makes it robust to those too.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the `()` characters that end up in your `progfiles` string. If you take them out, the substitution seems to work fine.

My suggestion is to ditch command for this particular purpose and use one of the other standard tools that Windows comes with. While my personal preference would be Powershell (since it's so much more powerful and expressive), you may just need something quick that you can integrate into existing `cmd.exe` stuff.

In that case, try the following VBScript file, `xlat.vbs`:

```
set arg = wscript.arguments
wscript.echo Replace(arg(0),arg(1),arg(2))
```

Your batch file then becomes something like, noting the *inner* `for /f` which captures the output of the VBS script and assigns it to the variable:

```
@echo off
SET build.dir=%~dp0%

set progfiles=%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%
if "%progfiles%"=="" set progfiles=%ProgramFiles%

set local.properties=%build.dir%local.properties

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%i in (%local.properties%) do (
    set local.dir=%%j
    for /f "delims=" %%x in ('cscript.exe //nologo xlat.vbs "!local.dir!" "[m]" "%progfiles%\MODULE"') do set local.dir=%%x
    echo !local.dir!
)
endlocal
```

Running that, I get the output:

```
C:\Test
C:\Program Files (x86)\MODULE\Test
```

which I think is what you were after.

Comment: hmmm....working off @foxidrive's suggestion, I get the proper-ish output just adding quotes:    SET local.dir="!local.dir:[m]=%progfiles%\MODULE!" -- still experimenting, but I think it might be the spaces in the path moreso than the paren.

Comment: @rguilbault, if you look again, you'll see you're actually getting the replacement *command* `[m]=...` rather than the replaced string.  In addition, if you set `progfiles` to be `"XYZZY PLUGH"`, you'll see your *original* code works with spaces just fine. Add back in the parens and the issue re-appears. No, I'm pretty certain `cmd` was written by an early drunk LSD-affected Microsoft individual and should be avoided for all but the simplest tasks :-) Still, you're free to vote as you see fit, assuming the answer works for you.

Comment: ha! I hear ya (re: cmd) -- it's weird that %progfiles% works fine outside of the FOR (actually, it works fine inside the FOR as well, as long as I add the quotes are the !local.dir:...! bit). I do appreciate the assistance, though...it's an interesting trick you suggested (one I wouldn't have thought of).

Comment: @paxdiablo The `()` are unquoted and which is a problem in a batch script, when inside a loop.   My previous comment re `=` was my mistake because I didn't read the question properly and had mistaken `local.properties` for a text string and not a file.  Mea Culpa.